# Half-half css layout padding and positioning problem

Tags: html, css, layout

Greetings,

I am trying to create a simple two-column layout: left half one colour, right half another colour with all the text aligned to the middle of the screen.

I have two problems I cannot find obvious solutions for (my css skills are poor):

1. White border around the divs.
2. When I introduce text padding to the columns they get bigger, cannot fit next to each other and the right column collapses under the left.

Here is the current css:

```
#left {
float:left;
width:50%;
height: 100%;
background-color:orange;
color:black;
text-align:right;
}
#right {
float:right;
width:50%;
height: 100%;
background-color:black;
color:orange;
}
```

Here is html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Tucolor</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="left">bleh</div>
<div id="right">mleh</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the 'white border' around the `div`s you can apply:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

and to allow for padding within the `div`s, I'd suggest wrapping the text in `p` tags, and applying either a [margin (JS Fiddle demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/8UfJ8/2/), or [padding (JS Fiddle demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/8UfJ8/1/), to those.

Answer (score 2):

@rince

for white border just write

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

or use `reset sheet` because some browser gave default padding to the body

&

2 . if you  given padding to the column or any object it's add width to it so,decrease height & width according to the padding .

for example :
if `width:100px;` & when we add `padding-left:10px;` to it .Then we written `width:90px;` instead of `100px`